# Unit Testing Method Arguments

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I hope this is doable. I want to use **Unit Testing** to validate method parameters.
I want to ensure that zero is not passed through as an argument.

> Code to Test

```
 public class TestParameter
 {
    public double divide(int dividend, int divisor)
    {
        double quotient = 0;

        if (divisor!=0)
        quotient= dividend / divisor;

        return quotient;
    }       
}
```

> Unit Test

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestIntro
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ZeroDivision()
    {
        TestParameter test = new TestParameter();
        double ans = test.divide(10, 0);
        //Assert.IsTrue();
        //I want to assert that divide does not allow 0 divisor as an argument
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the results of the method: what should it do if you pass 0 as the divisor? The behaviour seems to be that it returns 0, so test for that: pass in a range of dividends with a divisor of 0, and check that your method returns 0 in all of these cases. You're checking what your method returns when you call it in different ways, not how it's implemented internally.

Comment: @canton7 your comment suggests that I can only validate return values. Is that the case?

Comment: As CodeCaster's answer shows, you want to be throwing an exception from the method if it's given an invalid argument. Then if you want, you could write a unit test to verify that an exception is thrown when you pass the invalid argument.

Comment: @PholosoMams You should validate the *outputs* of your method: what it returns, what it throws, how it mutates its input parameters, etc. You can also pass it mocks, and check how it calls them. One of the great advantages of unit testing is that you can change how your method is implemented, then test that it still behaves the same: you can't do that if your unit test tests how the method is implemented, not how it behaves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer on a question in title

Unit-testing is a logic-based testing.

Testing method arguments doesn't make sense because method arguments is an *instruments* to build your own business-logic.

You can't test arguments.

#### Answer on a real question

You need to validate arguments in your main method like:

```cs
public class TestParameter
 {
    public double divide(int dividend, int divisor)
    {
        if (divisor == 0) // Validation
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument can't be '0'", nameof(divisor));

        return dividend / divisor;
    }       
}
```

Then test it in a test:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void ZeroDivision()
{
    TestParameter test = new TestParameter();
    Exception expectedException = null;
    try
    {
        double ans = test.divide(10, 0);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        expectedException = e;
    }
    Assert.IsNotNull(expectedException);
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => ...)` if your test framework supports it, instead of the try/catch/`Assert.IsNotNull`

Answer (score 4):

> I want to use Unit Testing to validate method parameters.

No, you don't. That's not what unit tests are for. Your unit tests are run during development, but after your code is compiled, you don't deploy your tests with your binaries. Not for consumption, anyway.

It's impossible to do this using a unit test, there's no replacement for this code that you can put in a unit test:

```
public double divide(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    if (divisor == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot be 0", nameof(divisor));

    // ...
}
```

You can control what your unit test passes to your method, but you cannot control what others will pass it when they call it. The validation will therefore have to take place inside the actual method, not in your tests.